# Adobe Acrobat Reader DC doesn't enable searching PDF content in Outlook search like Adobe Reader XI did

Tags: search, microsoft-outlook-2013, adobe-reader

I have many users who were previously able to search the contents of PDFs using the built-in Outlook search (Outlook 2010 and 2013 MSI and Outlook 2013 Click to Run versions) back when we had Adobe Reader XI installed.

Since replacing Adobe Reader XI with Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, they are no longer able to search the contents of PDFs from the Outlook search.

Is there something that I can do in Windows, Outlook or Adobe to restore the functionality that my users previously had? I believe there was an iFilter that previously assisted this in Adobe Reader XI (version 11.*)

This is on Windows 7. I have read that Windows 8+ has a PDF iFilter built-in to the system already so this would be a non issue.

I've found that updating OS and/or going back to Adobe Reader XI with the iFilter for XI works but I'm trying to find something that'll work with the Windows 7 and Adobe Acrobat Reader DC that we already have in place. I have already messed with the Windows Search settings on a test machine but everything looks correct. I haven't been able to find anything from Adobe about an iFilter for the DC version as it looks like they're leaving it up to the OS now.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you attempted already to rectify this problem?